# Nested Scroll View Not Scroll to Bottom of Activity

Tags: java, android, android-nestedscrollview

I am having an issue with nested scroll view when reach bottom.
Inside nestedScrollView I have a button, in bottom of page I have a input field to enter phone number. When press button, if phone number filed not filled, I want to scroll to Bottom of Activity to highlight input field.
But in my activity it scrolling only half, not scrolling till end.

I tried all beloved java codes to fix this issue, but all works same (Not reaching bottom, stops on middle).

Java Codes

```
CoordinatorLayout mainCoordinate = findViewById(R.id.mainCoordinate);
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.nestedScroll);
```

1.

```
//Scroll to bottom of view
nestedScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mainCoordinate.getBottom());
       }
});
```

2.

```
//Scroll to bottom of view
nestedScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
   }
});
```

3.

```
nestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        final int scrollViewHeight = nestedScrollView.getHeight();
        if (scrollViewHeight > 0) {
            nestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            final View lastView = nestedScrollView.getChildAt(nestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
            final int lastViewBottom = lastView.getBottom() + nestedScrollView.getPaddingBottom();
            final int deltaScrollY = lastViewBottom - scrollViewHeight - nestedScrollView.getScrollY();
            /* If you want to see the scroll animation, call this. */
            nestedScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, deltaScrollY);
            /* If you don't want, call this. */
            nestedScrollView.scrollBy(0, deltaScrollY);
        }
    }
});
```

XML Codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/mainCoordinate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexibleAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/flexible.example.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="258dp"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageMain"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="258dp"
                    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_effect_circle_card"
                    android:src="@drawable/back_button_white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="48dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/price.card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_back"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                card_view:contentPadding="8dp">

                .........................
                .........................
                .........................    

                //My Other All Views

                .........................
                .........................
                .........................

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/profile.card"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_back"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                card_view:contentPadding="8dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:gravity="start"
                         android:padding="5dp"
                         android:text="Phone No." />

                    <EditText
                         android:id="@+id/etPhone"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                         android:gravity="end"
                         android:hint="Enter your phone"
                         android:inputType="phone"
                         android:text=""/>

               </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBookNow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I attached a video that explains my exact problem [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12rrgS3lIfjKUVARLY5yBW0wpmNYuWfAq/view)
Please, Does anyone having a better way or other suggestion to fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Pls try Android layout inspector to check height of your NestedScroll.

Try to add

- `android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"` to Button.
- In NestedScrollView set layout heigh to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`